# Ubuntu Server: Read vs Write Activity Comparison?

Tags: server, 20.04, raid, disk, disk-usage

I run an instance of Ubuntu Server 20.04.3. What is the best method to check which operation the disks in RAID do more in relation to each other? Read and Write? Like Writes - 80%, Reads - 20%.

Answer (score 2):

You can [install and] run `iotop`,

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install iotop
```

I often run the following command,

```
sudo iotop -od2
```

Comment: This kind of helps, but tells the info for the very moment when it is happening, not overall. iotop is not new to me, anyway.

Comment: @lion, Have a second look at the manual, `man iotop`. There is batch mode and accumulated and timestamp, and you can set long intervals between printouts.